# MS CRM 2013 Online OAuth unsupported_grant_type - authorization_code

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that runs inside an iframe in MS CRM 2013. The web application uses the MS CRM web services (Organization web service) to retrieve and save data. To do so, it needs to authenticate. For on-premises we are using windows authentication and impersonate with the currently logged user in MS CRM (user id is passed to the iframe URL). It works like a charm.

However for MS CRM 2013 Online, since we want to avoid storing any user credentials in our application, we have chosen to use OAuth. Any suggestion how to achieve the same in a different way are most welcome since it does not seam right to use a method mostly for non-dot-net clients.

We are able to get the code calling: `https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&resource={1}&client_id={2}&redirect_uri={3}`. But when I ask for the token, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Request

Method: POST

URL: `https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0`

Header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: login.windows.net
Content-Length: 563
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Body:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&resource={2}
```

Response

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"ACS70003: The access grant \u0027authorization_code\u0027 is not supported...}
```

The comments under this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/05/17/using-oauth-2-0-authorization-code-grant-for-delegated-access-of-directory-via-aad-graph.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) suggest that this is a Azure AD bug but it should have been fixed by now, I guess. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Enoch

Comment: I have answered this question at >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408669/the-access-grant-authorization-code-is-not-supported-from-azure-ad-using-oauth/25419449

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to do it the "client-side-way".
I've tried Azure AD, but finds that it is much easier to built your "custom UI" as web resources (html/javascript/angular.js in my case) and then store them in CRM. Then you can communicate with CRM by using the OData JSON interface and IF you need to call external services where .Net is needed then call a custom [action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx). In this way you can combine HTML/JavaScript with custom .Net code if needed.

Comment: Take a look at this or O365 authentication: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx