# "The access grant authorization_code is not supported" from Azure AD using Oauth 2

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

I am in the middle of an  [Authorization Code Grant Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) with Azure AD.  Even though the documentation says the `grant_type` should be `authorization_code`, I am getting an error message about this property.

```
POST https://login.windows.net/SOME_AZURE_AD_UUID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=SECRET_CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=SECRET_CLIENT_SECRET
&code=SECRET_CODE
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=https://myserver.example.com/login/auth_return
&resource=https://myserver.example.com/
&scope=openid email
```

*(**edit**: whitespace added for clarity)*

The error I am getting back:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request
Content-Length: 436
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Request-Id: SOME_REQUEST_ID
X-Ms-Request-Id: SOME_REQUEST_ID
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=slicea; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, stsservicecookie=acs; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 14:44:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "correlation_id": "SOME_CORRELATION_ID",
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_codes": [
    70003
  ],
  "error_description": "
    ACS70003: The access grant 'authorization_code' is not supported.\r\n
    Trace ID: SOME_TRACE_UUID\r\n
    Correlation ID: SOME_CORRELATION_ID\r\n
    Timestamp: 2014-08-20 14:44:08Z",
  "timestamp": "2014-08-20 14:44:08Z",
  "trace_id": "SOME_TRACE_UUID"
}
```

*(whitespace added for clarity)*

This request does work if I change `grant_type` to `client_credentials` (but I have not found a way to use the resulting token for what I need).  It also works if I change some URLs to point to Google instead of Azure AD.

Is there a mistake with these requests or does the service genuinely not support the documented `grant_type` of `authorization_code`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug I believe, and it took me 2-3 days to figure it out. Please do the following to get it working,

1) Remove the "?api-version=1.0" from your URL. I know it sounds strange but trust me their documentation is a mess.

2) Add a "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header in your request (hence you'll have to encode the post data values ... for example redirect_url=(encodedURL) etc

3) Remove unnecessary fields from post data  [REFER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx)  ... it should be like

```
{
    'grant_type': "authorization_code",
    'resource': "your resource",
    'client_id': "your client Id",
    'redirect_uri': "your redirect URL",
    'client_secret': "your client secret",
    'code': "the code u got"
}
```

I see you have done point 2 so you'll need to do point 1 and you're good to go.

Furthermore, if you want to get access_token quickly(if nothing I said works for you), then pass "client_credentials" in grant_type and you'll get a smaller response with access_token. But if you want the complete response with refresh_token as well, you'll have to do all those steps.

**EDIT**:
There is one more mistake in their documentation, for Refresh Tokens >>> the URL should be **oauth2/token** and NOT **oauth2/authorize**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I was getting confused.  I was always posting it URLencoded but my debugging statement printed it as JSON.  I have updated the question to reflect what was posted more clearly.

Comment: So I have (1) removed `api-version` from the URL and (2) removed the `scope` from the body. Now I am getting a new error message, so that sounds like progress :)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to drop the (optional) `resource` and keep the `scope` so that it gives the email address back. I have accepted your answer because it led me down the right path but I suggest you update it because I really want that email address field.

Comment: Why don't you use Oauth "state" field for this? I mean you want to get back an email id I suppose... use oauth state field (protocol standard and is recommended for this call as well)? Furthermore, "resource" is very important because it tells which site you are trying authorize. Say you gave "https://graph.windows.net" and after that you wanted to access your Sharepoint ... say "blabla-my.sharepoint.com" then you'll get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'grant_type':"client_credentials",
'resource': "your resource",
'client_id': "your client Id",
'redirect_uri': "your redirect URL",
'client_secret': "your client secret",
```